# Show that $[\prod_{i=1}^N n_i] + 1 \geq \sqrt{N}(\bar{n} + 1)$

Tags: inequality, summation, induction

Following on from my [question here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4732651/784846), I am trying to show now that $\left[\prod_{i=1}^N n_i\right] + 1 \geq \sqrt{N}(\bar{n} + 1)$, where $\bar{n} = \frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N n_i$ and $n_i \in \mathbb{N}, n_i \geq 2$. I tried to show it by induction but I was not having much luck. I am not mathematician but it seems like it should be reasonably easy to prove, but alas! I have confirmed with some simulations (simulating $n_i$ for various $N$) with $N$ up to around 20 before overflow errors, so it looks promising that it should be true, but I am having a really difficult time proving it.

Comment: For $N=2$, $n_1 = n_2 = 2$ the inequality becomes $5 \ge \sqrt 2 \cdot 5$, which is wrong.  Same problem with $N=3$ and $N=4$ and all $n_i = 2$. – Am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: @MartinR I had a slight panic then, but RHS becomes $\sqrt{2} \cdot 2$ -- I missed the $\frac{1}{N}$ in the definition of the mean.

Comment: Now it makes more sense!

Comment: hey @MartinR I just posted another question related to this in case you have a solution/any tips for solving it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We'll prove this by induction on $N\geq 2$ (case $N=1$ is trivial).
Let $x=n_N$ and $$f(x) = \left(\prod_{k=1}^{N-1} n_k - \dfrac{\sqrt{N}}{N}\right)x + 1 - \sqrt{N}\left(\dfrac{\sum_{k=1}^{N-1}n_k}{N} + 1\right)$$
We want to prove that $f([2,+\infty[) \in \mathbb{R}_+$ (initial inequality written differently).

Notice that
$$ f'(x) = \prod_{k=1}^{N-1} n_k - \dfrac{\sqrt{N}}{N} \geq 2^{N-1} - \dfrac{\sqrt{N}}{N} \geq 0$$
Hence $f$ is increasing ie. $f(x) \geq f(2)$.
Finally,
\begin{align*}
f(2) &= 2\left(\prod_{k=1}^{N-1} n_k - \dfrac{\sqrt{N}}{N}\right) + 1 - \sqrt{N}\left(\dfrac{\sum_{k=1}^{N-1}n_k}{N} + 1\right)\\
&= 2\prod_{k=1}^{N-1} n_k + 2 - 1 - \sqrt{N}\left(\dfrac{\sum_{k=1}^{N-1}n_k}{N} + \dfrac{2}{N} +1\right)\\
&\overset{IH}\geq  2\sqrt{N-1}\left(\dfrac{\sum_{k=1}^{N-1}n_k}{N-1} + 1\right) - \sqrt{N}\left(\dfrac{\sum_{k=1}^{N-1}n_k}{N} + \dfrac{2}{N} +1\right)-1\\
&= \left(\sum_{k=1}^{N-1}n_k\right)\left(2\dfrac{\sqrt{N-1}}{N-1}-\dfrac{\sqrt{N}}{N}\right)+2\sqrt{N-1}-1-\dfrac{2\sqrt{N}}{N}-\sqrt{N}\\
&\geq 2(N-1)\left(2\dfrac{\sqrt{N-1}}{N-1}-\dfrac{\sqrt{N}}{N}\right)+2\sqrt{N-1}-1-\dfrac{2\sqrt{N}}{N}-\sqrt{N}\\
&= 6\sqrt{N-1}-1-\sqrt{N}-2\dfrac{\sqrt{N}}{N}\left(1+(N-1)\right)\\
&= 6\sqrt{N-1} - 3\sqrt{N} - 1 \geq 0
\end{align*}
The last inequality holds for $N\geq 2$.

There's probably an easier solution.

Comment: Thanks (again!) for the help :)

Comment: just one question, what does the $IH$ above the $\geq$ mean? I've not seen this before

Comment: "induction hypothesis"

Comment: thanks! I think this is the only step I don't understand, what exactly have we done here? I can't tell what the induction hypothesis is?

Comment: The induction hypothesis is the initial inequality with $N-1$ variables.
We have :
\begin{align*}
f(2) &= 2\prod_{k=1}^{N-1} n_k + 2 - 1 - \sqrt{N}\left(3+\sum_{k=1}^{N-1}n_k\right)\\
&= 2\left(\prod_{k=1}^{N-1} n_k + 1\right) - \sqrt{N}\left(3+\sum_{k=1}^{N-1}n_k\right)
\end{align*}
And then we apply the IH for $\prod_{k=1}^{N-1} n_k + 1$, ie :
$$ \prod_{k=1}^{N-1} n_k + 1 \geq \sqrt{N-1}\left(\sum_{k=1}^{N-1}n_k\right)$$
And we plug that inequality into the above expression of $f(2)$.

Comment: okay that makes sense! but have we shown the case for $N = 2$, since the final inequality is only true for $N \geq 3$?

Comment: After computing some values, I realized that the statement is false for $N=2,3,4$ (take all  $n_k=2$).
So you either need to change the minimum value of the $n_k$ (it is sufficient that $n_k \geq 6$, or change the minimum value of $N$

Comment: Sorry @TheFuser. I messed up my initial question, the $\bar{n}$ is actually the mean, so there should be an extra factor of $\frac{1}{N}$, so I believe it is still true.

Comment: I edited the original solution, I think we're good now!

Comment: Great, thanks a lot! @TheFuser

Comment: Hey @TheFuser I posted another question related to this in case you have any thoughts on it!

Answer (score 1):

Set $n_i = x_i + 2$ with $x_i \ge 0$. Then
$$
 1+\prod_{i=1}^N n_i = 1+\prod_{i=1}^N (x_i+2) \ge 1+2^N + 2^{N-1}\sum_{i=1}^N x_i \, .
$$
Now $1+2^N \ge 3 \sqrt N$ (proof below) and $2^{N-1} \ge 1 \ge \frac{1}{\sqrt N}$, therefore the expression is
$$
 \ge 3 \sqrt N + \frac{1}{\sqrt N}\sum_{i=1}^N x_i = \sqrt N \left(3 + \frac 1N \sum_{i=1}^N x_i \right) = \sqrt N \left(1 + \frac 1N \sum_{i=1}^N n_i \right) \, .
$$

---

It remains to show that $1+2^N \ge 3 \sqrt N$ for $N \ge 1$. For $N=1, 2, 3$ this can be verified directly. If $N \ge 4$ then $N=u^2$ with $u \ge 2$ and, using [Bernoulli's inequality,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli%27s_inequality)
$$
1+2^N - 3 \sqrt N = 1+(1+1)^{u^2} - 3u \ge 1+ (1+u^2) - 3u = (u-2)(u-1) \ge 0 \, .
$$

Comment: Thanks @MartinR !!!

Comment: can I ask where the inequality comes from in the first equation? is it from multinomial expansion?

Comment: @David: The term $2^N$ arises when you multiply $2$ from all factors, and the term $2^{N-1}x_i$ arises when you multiply $x_i$ from the $i$-th factor with $2$ from all other factors.

Comment: @David: In other words, from expanding the product $\prod_{i=1}^N (x_i+2)$ we keep only the terms which contain no $x_i$ or just one $x_i$ and omit the terms where two or more of the $x_i$ are multiplied. For example $$(x_1+2)(x_2+2)(x_3+2) = x_1x_2x_3 + 2(x_1x_2+x_1x_3+x_2x_3) + 4(x_1+x_2+x_3) + 8 \ge  4(x_1+x_2+x_3) + 8 $$

Comment: Thanks @MartinR -- I think that is what I meant when I said multinomial expansion. I.e. you have basically expanded multiplication out of the brackets and dropped some terms (which we know to be positive) so that is why it is bigger than the other term. I could see where the $2^N$ came from but was just unsure if that is where the $2^{N-1}\sum_i x_i$ term came from!